# How to generate dynamic expiry dates like 3 months, 6 months, 9 months and 12 months from the today date in php

Tags: php

I want to create dynamic expiry date from the today to next 3 months or 6 months or 9 months or 12 months using PHP
I tried but it's not working

```
$today_date= strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$data['expiry_date'] = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($valid_months,date("Y-m-d"))));
```

display code like this

```
<?php foreach($mydata as value){
    $date_expire=date('d M Y',strtotime($value->expiry_date));
    $register_date=date_create(date('d M Y ',$value->created));
    $expiry_date=date_create($date_expire);
    $diff = date_diff($register_date,$expiry_date);
    echo $diff->format('%a Days');
}
```

I am getting output like this

```
2348824 Days // count remaining days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `DateTime` class and the associated methods available such as `add` and `diff`

```
$interval=new DateInterval('P3M');
$now = new DateTime();
$start=new DateTime();
$end=new DateTime( date( DATE_ATOM, strtotime('+1 year') ) );
$end->add( $interval );


while( $start->add( $interval ) <= $end ){
    echo $diff = $start->diff( $now )->format('%a') . '<br>';
}
```

This will output:

```
92
182
274
366
```

Comment: $interval=new DateInterval('P3M'); in this line what mean by 'P3M'

Comment: it means a date interval period of 3 months

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand from your question,i think you just need this.

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+3 months'));
```

If it Doesn't help , feel free to comment .